# How's Python today concerning Interfaces for documentation purposes?

Tags: python, interface

I've read [this post](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-interfaces-are-not-java.html) from a long time ago and I've tried to create my own trivial example:

```
class IExample(Interface):
    """ An object that serves as an Example."""

class IExamp(IExample):
    """ Examp object representing the current state of Example."""

    def set_state(state):
        """ Sets the state of Example."""

    def get_state():
        """ Gets the state of Example."""

class Example():

    def __init__(self, state=0):
        self.state = state

class Examp(Example):

    def __init__(self, state=0):
        Example.__init__(self, state)

    def set_state(self, state):
        self.state = state

    def get_state(self):
        return self.state

e = Examp()
print(e.get_state())
```

And I get an error (Which should be obvious to many oldschool Python programmers, but not for me, since I've learned Python in 2012 or whatever).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Interface' is not defined
```

And when I type "Python 3.4 Interface" on Google, I get one hundred thousand links related to Graphical User Interface programming, instead of Interfaces (I've also searched on Python docs, and there's nothing about it).

So, how's Python today concerning Interfaces for documentation purposes? Did they BURY the concept so deep that no one can find anything about it anymore? Is it something lost in the realm of the old python versions? If that's the case, why it has been "dropped off"? Is there an "official" post about it somewhere? Do people actually use Interfaces for documentation purposes in Python **today**? If they do, **how** they do it?

Comment: Jeebus! Look at the date on that article! If you really need interfaces then check out Pythons ``abc`` module, but if you want to follow the article download ``zope.interface``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Interface` class comes from the [`zope.interface`](http://docs.zope.org/zope.interface/README.html) module, which explains why you didn't find it in the official documentation.

The thing is, Zope isn't used *that* often anymore (at least, not on a lot of new projects). You'll still see it in the wild on legacy code, but not a lot of new code.

If you want to stick with Python stdlib sources, you could probably use [abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) for a similar purpose.

Truthfully, though, interfaces aren't used much at all in Python code anymore.